# conjunctions and comma which one should I use?

Tags: commas

I got the sentence from a novel "The kite runner".

I thought the conjunctions need to connect the two sentences instead of comma.

But these two sentences use the comma, could you please explain to me?

378p
I tried to not look at the bathtub. It was clean now, someone had wiped off the blood, spread new floor mats on the floor and scrubbed the walls.

==> Isn't "someone had wiped off the blood" perfect sentence? I thought it should connected with "and" not " , "

like below,
It was clean now and someone had wiped off the blood, spread new floor mats on the floor and scrubbed the walls.

Could you explain to me?

Comment: It's called a comma splice. It is considered poor grammar but it is a very common way to write. Putting "and" every time would not be much better.

Comment: This is okay in informal writing.  In formal writing one would use a semicolon after "now."

Comment: It's odd, but a child is speaking in a non-English-speaking country.

Comment: The reason comma splices are considered bad writing is because they force the reader to go back and rehear the comma as a full stop, because the part before the comma is a complete sentence and shouldn't have a comma intonation, and that changes the meaning of the whole utterance.

Answer (score 1):

No, conjunctions are not needed between complete sentences. Nor are they needed between independent clauses of a single sentence, which may have been what you meant. But you are correct that what you quote is not punctuated as recommended by any style guide I am familiar with. However, your suggested revision is not correct either.

> He drove to the city. And there he met his wife. And, after they met, they had dinner. And later they went to the theater. And they stayed the night at a hotel. And the next day, they drove home.

None of those “ands” is necessary.

Most style guides give a rule somewhat along these lines:

**Two or more independent clauses can be combined in a single sentence if separated by a comma and a conjunction or if separated by a semi-colon or colon.**

However, a series of partial clauses with the same subject and different verbs is not considered a combination of independent clauses: it is considered as a single clause and punctuated like a list.

So, if you use the Oxford comma, as I do, you would punctuate your sentence as follows

> The bathroom was clean now; someone had wiped off the blood, spread new floor mats, and scrubbed the walls

or

> The bathroom was clean now, and someone had wiped off the blood, spread new floor mats, and scrubbed the walls

If you do not use the Oxford comma, the very last comma in each of those sentences would be dropped.

Personally, I prefer the semi-colon here because the second clause is not logically independent of the first clause. The logical conjunction to go here is “because,” but it is so obvious as to be unneeded.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved a big question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comma splice, and is generally considered a fault in writing.

There are some "grammar" rules that native speakers follow almost instinctively and rarely make mistakes.  Native speakers rarely use "the" in the wrong way, for example.  But there are other "rules" that native speakers learn at school and make lots of "mistakes".  The comma splice is one of these.  It is very common.

Some comma splices are intentional. The author wants the two sentences to be considered as a whole and doesn't want the "formality" of a semicolon. If you read Hemingway, you will find comma splices and run-on sentences throughout.  Hemingway is trying to create the flow and informality of a person's internal monologue. Some comma splices are not intentional and represent a simple error.

Here I'd note this is the thoughts and narration of a young boy. I speculate that Hosseini, the author, thought that a semicolon would look too "grown-up" to be in the mind of the boy, and chose the comma splice on purpose for that effect.

Comment: Thank you so much!  it helps me to understand the same error in the book.